# How I can Populate TableView with database data (Objects from NamedQuery)

Tags: arrays, tableview

This is my **TableView**

```
 @FXML
    private TableView<Donante> tblDonantes;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Donante, String> colApellido = new TableColumn<>("Apellido");
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Donante, String> colNombre = new TableColumn<>("Nombre");
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Donante, Long> colCUILCUIT = new TableColumn<>("CUIL");
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Donante, LocalDate> colFechaExtraccion = new TableColumn<>("Fecha Extracción");
```

My **Columns**

```
            tblDonantes.setPlaceholder(new Label("No se encontraron Donantes"));
            colApellido.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Donante, String>("apellido"));
            colApellido.setMinWidth(250);
            colNombre.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Donante, String>("nombre"));
            colNombre.setMinWidth(250);
            colCUILCUIT.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Donante, Long>("cuil"));
            colCUILCUIT.setMinWidth(100);
            colFechaExtraccion.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Donante, LocalDate>("fecha"));
            colFechaExtraccion.setMinWidth(150);t
tblDonantes.getColumns().addAll(colApellido, colNombre, colCUILCUIT, colFechaExtraccion);
```

This query `Query buscarDonantes = AreaPrincipal.em.createNamedQuery("Donante.buscarSinDonaciones");`return this image [Donors list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3b3Tp.png)
I need populate my tabeview (tblDonantes) with donors list...I try this, but I see nothing...

```
ObservableList<Donante> listaDonantes = FXCollections.observableArrayList(buscarDonantes.getResultList());
            tblDonantes.setItems(listaDonantes);
```

I try this too...

```
List<Object[]> resultList = (List<Object[]>) buscarDonantes.getResultList();    
for (int i = 0; i < resultList.size(); i++) {
      System.out.print(resultList.get(i)[0] + resultList.get(i)[1] + resultList.get(i)[2] + resultList.get(i)[3]);
            }
```

Of course I see data...in console, but I need y my tableView...¿What's wrong?
TIA...Ernesto

Answer (score 0):

In answer my own question (thank you Chris at Komposta.net):
**First**: Create a "generic" model...

```
package ar.dignitas.balthus.model;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Generica {
    private ArrayList<Object> data;
    public Generica(Object... args) {
        data = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(args));
    }
    public Object get0() {
        return data.get(0);
    }
    public Object get1() {
        return data.get(1);
    }
    public Object get2() {
        return data.get(2);
    }
    public Object get3() {
        return data.get(3);
    }
    public Object get4() {
        return data.get(4);
    }
    public Object get5() {
        return data.get(5);
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return data.toString();
    }  
}
```

**Second:** TableView little bit modified

```
   @FXML
   private TableView<Generica> tblDonantes;
   @FXML
   private TableColumn<Generica, String> colApellido = new TableColumn<>("Apellido");
   @FXML
   private TableColumn<Generica, String> colNombre = new TableColumn<>("Nombre");
   @FXML
   private TableColumn<Generica, String> colCUILCUIT = new TableColumn<>("CUIL");
   @FXML
   private TableColumn<Generica, String> colFechaExtraccion = new TableColumn<>("Fecha 
   Extracción");
```

**Third:** Cell columns!

```
colCUILCUIT.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> new 
    SimpleStringProperty(cellData.getValue().get0().toString()));
colCUILCUIT.setMinWidth(100);
colApellido.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> new 
    SimpleStringProperty(cellData.getValue().get1().toString()));
colApellido.setMinWidth(250);
colNombre.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> new 
    SimpleStringProperty(cellData.getValue().get2().toString()));       
colNombre.setMinWidth(250);
colFechaExtraccion.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> new 
    SimpleStringProperty(cellData.getValue().get3().toString()));
colFechaExtraccion.setMinWidth(150);

tblDonantes.getColumns().addAll(colCUILCUIT, colApellido, colNombre, colFechaExtraccion);
```

**Fourth...and finally:**

```
    btnBuscarTodos.setOnAction(event -> {
                limpiarColumnasTblDonantes();
            /*****************************************************************************
* The SELECT clause queries more than one column or entity, the 
* results are aggregated in an object array (Object[]) in the java.util.List 
* returned by getResultList( ).     
*****************************************************************************/
    Query buscarDonantes = AreaPrincipal.em.createNamedQuery("Donante.buscarSinDonaciones");
    List<Object[]> listaDonantes = FXCollections.observableArrayList(buscarDonantes.getResultList());
    ObservableList<Generica> data = FXCollections.observableArrayList();    
        for (Object[] filaRad : listaDonantes) { //for para recorrer las filas
                    data.add(new Generica(filaRad));
                }
                tblDonantes.setItems(data);     
            });
```

I don't know is the better way to achievement this...for now, this code works. With more time to study, I'm shure can improve it.

@Ernesto